# IBM Cognos SDK login with custom authentication provider

Tags: java, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am trying to login to cognos using the SDK but keep getting the following error:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: Client
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: CM-REQ-4342 An error occurred with the client.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/}exception:
                    <severity>error</severity>
                    <errorCode>cmAuthenticateFailed</errorCode>
                    <ns1:message>
                        <messageString>CM-CAM-4005 Unable to authenticate. Check your security directory server connection and confirm the credentials entered at login.</messageString>
                    <detail>
                    <exception xmlns:cm="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="bus:CAMException">
                        <severity xsi:type="bus:severityEnum">error</severity>
                        <errorCode>-36</errorCode>
                        <errorCodeString xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">camAuthUserRecoverable</errorCodeString>
                        <messages soapenc:arrayType="bus:message[2]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                            <item xsi:type="bus:message">
                                <messageString xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                            </item>
                            <item xsi:type="bus:message">
                                <nestingLevel xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</nestingLevel>
                                <messageString xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string"> Enter your authentication credentials.</messageString>
                            </item>
                        </messages>
                        <promptInfo xsi:type="bus:promptInfo">
                            <captions soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                                <item xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                                <item xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string"> Enter your authentication credentials.</item>
                            </captions>
                            <displayObjects soapenc:arrayType="bus:displayObject[6]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">text</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">FormUsername</name>
                                    <caption xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">User ID</caption>
                                </item>
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">textnoecho</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">FormUserPassword</name>
                                    <caption xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">Password</caption>
                                </item>
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">singleselect</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">CAMSiteName</name>
                                    <caption xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">Site</caption>
                                    <promptOptions soapenc:arrayType="bus:promptOption[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">1</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">Mexico</value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</default>
                                        </item>
                                    </promptOptions>
                                </item>
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">singleselect</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">CAMAuthType</name>
                                    <caption xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">Authentication Type</caption>
                                    <promptOptions soapenc:arrayType="bus:promptOption[5]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">3</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">AD/Kerberos </value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</default>
                                        </item>
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">1</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">SRP</value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</default>
                                        </item>
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">6</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">PKI</value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</default>
                                        </item>
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">5</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">RSA SecurID</value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</default>
                                        </item>
                                        <item xsi:type="bus:promptOption">
                                            <id xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">4</id>
                                            <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">LDAP</value>
                                            <default xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</default>
                                        </item>
                                    </promptOptions>
                                </item>
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">hidden</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">h_CAM_action</name>
                                    <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">logonAs</value>
                                </item>
                                <item xsi:type="bus:displayObject">
                                    <type xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">hidden</type>
                                    <name xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">CAMNamespace</name>
                                    <value xml:space="preserve" xsi:type="xsd:string">BLNSProvider</value>
                                </item>
                            </displayObjects>
                        </promptInfo>
                    </exception>
                    </detail>
                    </ns1:message>
```

I know that my username and password are accurate.

Here's the code, it's been ripped from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/development/how_to/page565.html).

```
public class CognosTest {
    private static String dispatcherURL = "http://domain:port/p2pd/servlet/dispatch";
    private static String nameSpaceID = "BLNSProvider";
    private static String userName = "username";
    private static String password = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContentManagerService_PortType cmService = null;
        ContentManagerService_ServiceLocator cmServiceLocator = new ContentManagerService_ServiceLocator();
        StringBuffer credentialXML = new StringBuffer();
        String encodedCredentials;
        XmlEncodedXML xmlCredentials = new XmlEncodedXML();

        // Step 1. Connect to Cognos services
        try {
            URL url = new URL(dispatcherURL);
            cmService = cmServiceLocator.getcontentManagerService(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Step 2. Logon to Cognos.
        credentialXML.append("<credential>");
        credentialXML.append("<namespace>").append(nameSpaceID).append("</namespace>");
        credentialXML.append("<username>").append(userName).append("</username>");
        credentialXML.append("<password>").append(password).append("</password>");
        credentialXML.append("</credential>");

        encodedCredentials = credentialXML.toString();
        xmlCredentials.set_value(encodedCredentials);

        try {
            cmService.logon(xmlCredentials, null);
            SOAPHeaderElement temp = ((Stub)cmService).getResponseHeader("http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/", "biBusHeader");
            BiBusHeader CMbibus = (BiBusHeader)temp.getValueAsType(new QName ("http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/", "biBusHeader"));
            ((Stub)cmService).setHeader("http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/", "biBusHeader", CMbibus);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Step 3. Log out from Cognos.
        try {
            cmService.logoff();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The difference between my code and the one in that document is the namespace id. The cognos I'm trying to connect to, uses a custom Java authentication provider with the Java class name

```
com.bmc.bbds.auth.cognos.providers.BDSAuthenticationProvider
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The class name of the Custom Java Authentication Provider (CJAP) doesn't matter for SDK authentication purposes.  The namespace ID is the relevant factor, which can be found in Cognos Configuration on the namespace node with the title "Namespace ID."  Therefore, `BLNSProvider` may be the appropriate value.

Based on the response from Cognos you included, it looks like your CJAP requires more fields than just your standard user name and password.  You would need to include entries for these values in your `credentialXml` object that you send as your authentication to successfully authenticate to Cognos with that CJAP.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I do have to select a user role when logging in to the web application. I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion BTW, I had given up on trying to use the cognos sdk!

Comment: Is there any way I can figure out the tag names inside which I have to put the extra credentials?